# The package 'analytics-react-native' can't access a custom native module while testing in react native

Tags: react-native, analytics, ts-jest, segment-analytics

analytics-react-native giving me this warning when I run test on it.

```
    console.warn
      The package 'sovran-react-native' doesn't seem to be linked. Make sure: 
      
      - You have run 'pod install'
      - You rebuilt the app after installing the package
      - You are not using Expo managed workflow
```

and

```
 The package 'analytics-react-native' can't access a custom native module. Make sure: 
      
      - You have run 'pod install'
      - You rebuilt the app after installing the package
      - You are not using Expo managed workflow
```

I tried to mock it like

```
jest.mock('@segment/analytics-react-native', () => ({
  setup: jest.fn(),
  identify: jest.fn(),
  reset: jest.fn(),
}));
```

but it gives error

`Super expression must either be null or a function`

What is the proper way to test it or create mock of it?